# Analysis of intervals between events

Tags: time-series

I have been investigating the possibility of using the interval between uncommon events to test for changes in the frequency of such events over time.
As an example, say that the event is breaking a record in some sporting competition. This might occur at most a few times a year, and the data segmentation problem (whether an event falls within a certain interval of observation) causes the usual events-per-year analysis, usually a GLM with a Poisson link, to be strongly affected by even a single event without a very long series.
I first thought of sampling different observation intervals, and then decided to discard the intervals entirely and see if the intervals between events were associated with their serial position. This seemed to be a more powerful test in the data I had. Apparently this was an accepted procedure some 50-60 years ago, but I have not been able to find much in the recent literature. I'm pretty sure that this is related to analyzing the frequency of extreme weather events and the like, but I am not familiar with that field.
Anyone out there know whether this type of test has been superceded by something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem but very tricky.It can be found by googling Intermittent Demand , Sparse Data Analysis and some other "names". We deal with time series data where there are two random variables ; The interval and the actual demand at each point.We have not experimented with cases like yours where the demand is ALWAYS a "1" but we see no reason that our approach wouldn't work[image: plot of demand and forecasts over time].  What we have found to be useful is to model the rate ( in your case 1/interval ) as it can be prdicted from Interval. This approach allows you to detect level changes in rate and of course unusual rates ( pulses). Try googling "analysis of time series with many zero values" and you will get some information on dealing with this "tricky problem".

Comment: Thanks for those tips, IrishStat. I have picked up a few more references and looked at a lot of "extreme weather event" analyses. The latter have mostly been lacking in explicit methods. I'll try using rate, as it should be more intuitive when plotted. I now have to explain that an increase in the smoothed interval means a decrease in the rate.